# Writing to another page in html

Tags: javascript, html

Essentially I have one HTML Script, in the javascript portion of the HTML code, I have a few variables. Essentially how do I get those values to interact with another url location.

To rephrase, Let's say I have this URL, containing the variables in that script: www.example.com/stuff. Now I want to use those variables to interact with www.example.com/stuff2.

How would I do that?

Comment: I could be wrong but I feel like that would not be possible with just javascript.  I would think you'd need a server language like PHP to do that.  Can you give a little more details what exactly you are trying to do?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `locaStorage` or `sessionStorage` for that:

In one page use:

```
<script>
      let var1 = "some data";
      let var2 = "other data";
      localStorage.setItem("data", {var1, var2});
</script>
```

In the other page get the data previously saved using:

```
<script>
    let data = localStorage.getItem("data");
    console.log(data.var1);
    console.log(data.var2);
</script>
```

Note: The same syntax works for `sessionStorage`

Answer (score 0):

You can assign variable globally

file 1

```
window.var1 ="value"
```

file 2

```
window.var2 = window.var1;
```

Comment: Why would you set another window var to the already set var from the previous page?

Comment: just an example to show that variables between files can be accessible.

Comment: Sure, but setting the first window var to a different widow var in a different file is pointless. You just need to access it, not set another one. If you are changing the data, then change the first var created.

Comment: var1 is accessed in file 2 and assigned to another variable.

Comment: Yeah, another window var. The point is, it is cluttering the window unnecessarily. If you want to access the window var in the new file script, just set a var using `var otherPageData = window.var1;`.

Comment: Yes that's i know, but then var otherpageData = 'abc' cannot be accessed in file1. Got my point?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179058/discussion-between-codemonkey-and-waqar-adil).

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly interpret your question, the solution would be to link the javascript also on the second page with `<script> </ script>`